# How to get the index path of a UICollectionView header when using a tap gesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I get the touch point using locationInView and pass this to the collection view's indexPathForItemAtPoint. I will get an index path for a cell, but never a UICollectionReusableView (header/footer), as it always returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too late to help on this but perhaps someone else will hit this as I did.  The problem is there is no meaningful indexPath for the header (it appears to always return 0,0).

Anyway, when I get the point, instead of the indexPath I'm checking to see whether it is inside the subview for the header:

```
CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:collectionView];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,140.0f,140.0f), point))
   NSLog(@"Point was inside header");
```

This works in my instance only because I know the size of the header and can safely assume its position within the collectionview because the collectionView has only one section (0).

HTH

Answer (score 6):

The header doesn't really have an indexPath; it reports as row 0, but so does the first cell in the section.

You can solve this problem easily by making a simple subclass of UITapGestureRecognizer that has an Integer property, just put the following interface and empty implementation at the top of the View Controller's `.m` file:

```
@interface HeaderTapRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger sectionNumber;
@end

@implementation HeaderTapRecognizer
@end
```

When you supply the supplementary view, just add one of these recognizers and set the section number:

```
HeaderTapRecognizer *recognizer = [[HeaderTapRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(headerTapped:)];
recognizer.sectionNumber = indexPath.section;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Now you can access the section number in the action block:

```
- (void)headerTapped:(id)sender
{
    HeaderTapRecognizer *htr = sender;
    NSInteger sectionNumber = htr.sectionNumber;
    NSLog(@"Header tapped for index Section %d",sectionNumber);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand this at all. Where do you get the indexPath anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I would create and attach a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to each header view. Another option would be to provide your a custom subclass of `UIControl` for each header view.

Comment: I've done the tap gesture recognizer, but using a single instance on the collection view instead of one for each header, since this is more efficient. I'm really just looking for how to get the index path of a header based upon a point.

Comment: I don't think having multiple tap recognizers will be a problem, but in that case you can use a custom header view... If your question is really "how do I get the index path for a tap on a header view in a collection view" you should ask that :)

Comment: I asked this way to give more context, in case there was some bug or issue in indexPathForItemAtPoint if using a tap gesture. Yes, the real issue is probably "how do I get the index path for a tap on a header view in a collection view?".